# How to split the HTML code from string

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I  have the string value with html code . like following

```
 var stringData =  "My name is khan  <ul><li>welo</li><li>sdlld</li><li>ssal</li><li>asalas</li>      <li>aslaS</li></ul> to <ul><li>welo</li><li>sdlld</li><li>ssal</li><li>asalas</li><li>aslaS</li></ul><ol><li>HI BOY&nbsp;</li><li>WWF</li></ol>."
```

i want to HTML code alone from string.

```
var htmlCode = <ul><li>welo</li><li>sdlld</li><li>ssal</li><li>asalas</li><li>aslaS</li></ul> to <ul><li>welo</li><li>sdlld</li><li>ssal</li><li>asalas</li><li>aslaS</li></ul><ol><li>HI BOY&nbsp;</li><li>WWF</li></ol>.
```

Notes: In string , My name is khan is dynamic content so  we will have other text also  instead of "My name is khan" .

```
Ex: " Hi how are <ul><li>welo</li><li>sdlld</li><li>ssal</li><li>asalas</li><li>aslaS</li></ul> to <ul><li>welo</li><li>sdlld</li><li>ssal</li><li>asalas</li><li>aslaS</li></ul><ol><li>HI BOY&nbsp;</li><li>WWF</li></ol>."
```

so we should  not use split by khan or space(split(' ')). please give the solution for above problem

Comment: do you want to put html code in a variable without use strings?

Comment: are you expecting a `.` at the end of html code?

Comment: is your html code content the same? because if it is, you can just grab the <ul> tag and everything after it

Answer (score 1):

You could substring from the first index of "<" like this:

```
var htmlCode = stringData.slice(stringData.indexOf("<"), stringData.length);
```

or simply

```
var htmlCode = stringData.substring(stringData.indexOf("<"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var stringData = "var stringData =  "My name is khan  <ul><li>welo</li><li>sdlld</li><li>ssal</li>....";
var n = stringData.indexOf("<ul>");

if (n !== -1) {
   var htmlString = stringData.substring(n, stringData.length)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about getting substring starting with first '<' and ending with last '>'

Answer (score 0):

if you are sure of your markup is open-ended and valid and in a single line, you can use

```
stringData.match(/(<.*>).$/)[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's `.children` method, which will leave out any text nodes:

```js
var stringData =  "My name is khan  <ul><li>welo</li><li>sdlld</li><li>ssal</li><li>asalas</li>      <li>aslaS</li></ul> to <ul><li>welo</li><li>sdlld</li><li>ssal</li><li>asalas</li><li>aslaS</li></ul><ol><li>HI BOY&nbsp;</li><li>WWF</li></ol>.";
var htmlOnly = $('<div/>').html( $('<div/>').html( stringData ).children() ).html();


//DEMO ONLY
$('.before').text( stringData );
$('.after').text( htmlOnly );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

BEFORE:<br><div class="before"></div>

AFTER:<br><div class="after"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use package HTMLAgilityPack

its used for extract values on the basis of tags

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var htmlCode = $.grep($.parseHTML(stringData), function(html) {
  return html.nodeType !== 3
});
```

```js
var stringData =  "My name is khan  <ul><li>welo</li><li>sdlld</li><li>ssal</li><li>asalas</li>      <li>aslaS</li></ul> to <ul><li>welo</li><li>sdlld</li><li>ssal</li><li>asalas</li><li>aslaS</li></ul><ol><li>HI BOY&nbsp;</li><li>WWF</li></ol>.";
    var htmlCode = $.grep($.parseHTML(stringData), function(html) {
      return html.nodeType !== 3
    });
$("body").append(htmlCode)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```